# How to write an SQL statement for example below

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 database tables below:

Question Table

```
QuestionId(Pk)  SessionId(PK)   Question
1               AAA             my name is
2               AAA             my age is
1               AAB             my DOB is
```

Image_Question Table

```
ImageQuestionId(Pk)  ImageId   SessionId   QuestionId
1                    1         AAB         1
2                    2         AAA         2 
3                    3         AAA         1
```

What I want to happen is that if the user deletes this row from the Question Table:

```
1               AAB         my DOB is
```

I want it to delete the corresponding row in the Image_Question Table by referring to both the SessionId and Question Id. As in the deleted row from the Question Table consists of SessionId = AAB and QuestionId = 1, it should delete the corresponding row from the Image_Question table where it contains SessionId = AAB AND QuestionId = 1, meaning that the only row that should be deleted from the Image Question is below:

```
1                    1         AAB         1
```

This is because both the SessionId and QuestionId match with the deleted row from the Question Table.

Does anyone know how to write the SQL code for this?

UPDATE:

Below is what I tried?

```
ALTER TABLE Image_Question ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SessionQuestion FOREIGN KEY (SessionId,QuestionId) REFERENCES Question (SessionId,QuestionId) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Sorry, sessionId is also a primary key in Question Table

Comment: @njk I update question which include sql statement I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it entirely right with your constraint. There must be something wrong in the basic table definition. Maybe you post your `CREATE TABLE` statements. My experiments all succeed. Have a look along my log:

I have tried it right in the create table in the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2cf7/1) and it works:

```
...
                            FOREIGN KEY (QuestionId,SessionId) 
                             REFERENCES Question(QuestionId,SessionId)
                             ON DELETE CASCADE
...
```

But what you want is to add it afterwards. So I made another [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06395/1) which also works when I add the constraint later:

```
ALTER TABLE Image_Question ADD CONSTRAINT
                           FOREIGN KEY (QuestionId,SessionId) 
                             REFERENCES Question(QuestionId,SessionId)
                             ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Only thing is that this seems to be exactly the same thing you do:

```
ALTER TABLE Image_Question ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SessionQuestion 
                            FOREIGN KEY (SessionId,QuestionId) 
                            REFERENCES Question (SessionId,QuestionId) 
                            ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I event tried giving the contraint a name in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a44d6/1). Same result.

EDIT: Do you have an `INDEX` on your `QUESTION` table so that the `FOREIGN KEY` correctly references? I realized your `FOREIGN KEY` is different sequence `SessionID,QuestionID` rather than `QuestionId,SessionId` which is okay, as long as your `INDEX` in the `QUESTION` table also is in that order.

EDIT 2: The full thing here:

```
CREATE TABLE Question (QuestionId INT      NOT NULL, 
                       SessionId  CHAR(3)  NOT NULL,
                       Question   CHAR(10) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO Question VALUES (1,'AAA','my name is');
INSERT INTO Question VALUES (2,'AAA','my age is');
INSERT INTO Question VALUES (1,'AAB','my DOB is');

-- This is how to add a primary key afterwards
ALTER TABLE QUESTION ADD PRIMARY KEY(SessionId,QuestionId);

CREATE TABLE Image_Question (ImageQuestionId INT     NOT NULL, 
                             ImageId          INT     NOT NULL,
                             SessionId        CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
                             QuestionId       INT     NOT NULL,
                            PRIMARY KEY (ImageQuestionId)
                            ) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO Image_Question VALUES (1,1,'AAB',1);
INSERT INTO Image_Question VALUES (2,2,'AAA',2);
INSERT INTO Image_Question VALUES (3,3,'AAA',1);

-- This is how to just add an index afterwards
CREATE INDEX par_ind on Image_Question (SessionId,QuestionId);

ALTER TABLE Image_Question ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CONSTRAINT_NAME
                           FOREIGN KEY (SessionId,QuestionId) 
                             REFERENCES Question(SessionId,QuestionId)
                             ON DELETE CASCADE;

delete from Question where QuestionId = 1 and SessionId = 'AAB';
```

And as [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16839/1)

Comment: The problem was that the question table was not InnoDB, other tables were

Comment: Ah, very good you found that out. Glad that my examples helped you to solve your problem. To be honest, I also learnt something.

Comment: I made examples here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16839/1 It is `CREATE INDEX` or `ALTER TABLE ... ADD PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: Than you very much for your help and answers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Image_Question 
WHERE QuestionID = 1 AND SessionId = AAB;
```

Comment: I don't mean that, I meant how can I add a constraint to multiple columns then be able to delete the rows using ON DELETE CASCADE. I included an example in my question on what I tried

Answer (score 0):

Using foreign key constraints, you must have unique ways of identifying records on both tables. Since you have a compound primary key on the `Questions` table (`QuestionId` & `SessionId(PK)`), you will need to make a constraint that references a compound key. Therefore, you'll need to make a key compound key on the `Image_Question` table (`ImageQuestionId` & `SessionId`).

Comment: Can you provide a sample code on how this could be written in SQL if you don't mind please?